# Add a delay to jQuery fadeIn function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a delay to my fadeIn function in jQuery. The purpose of the code is that when 'topmods' or 'dailyskins' button is pressed it will hide/show the other parent div.

Currently when i press the div 'topmods' is does hide the div 'dailyskins' though the content of 'topmods' goes below 'dailyskins' for a split second until 'dailyskins' has finished fading out.

I think this would be solved by adding a delay to both fadeIn and Out, though i don't know how to add this,

Please could you add a delay of 200ms to each of the fadeIn segments.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

     $("#topmods").hide();


jQuery('#dropdailyskin').live('click', function(event) {        
     jQuery('#dailyskins').fadeIn('show');
});

jQuery('#dropdailyskin').live('click', function(event) {        
     jQuery('#topmods').fadeOut('show');
});


 jQuery('#dropdownmods').live('click', function(event) {        
     jQuery('#dailyskins').fadeOut('show');
});

 jQuery('#dropdownmods').live('click', function(event) {        
     jQuery('#topmods').fadeIn('show');
});
```

Thanks

Comment: What you are looking for is the `setTimeout` function in javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout

Comment: Thanks, but i have no experience with jQuery or JS and have no idea how to implement this,

Comment: Also note that the `.live()` event is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 – you can replace it with `.on()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a timeout before executing your function using this:

```
setTimeout(function(){jQuery('#dailyskins').fadeIn('show')}, 200);
```

Comment: ive replaced the jQuery('#dailyskins').fadeIn('show'); line with what you suggested and it no longer works

Comment: What is the error thrown in the JavaScript console?

Comment: How would i check that? I just know it don't work as i replaced the code and refreshed the webpage I'm work on,

Comment: [Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('.customform').customform()')
 (anonymous function) (responsee.js, line 302)
 l (jquery-1.8.3.min.js, line 2)
 fireWith (jquery-1.8.3.min.js, line 2)
 ready (jquery-1.8.3.min.js, line 2)
 A (jquery-1.8.3.min.js, line 2)

Comment: Do you have other javascript files included that might be causing an error?

Comment: nope, just the one, is there no easier way of doing this ?

Comment: could you perhaps create jsfiddle.net of your script?

Comment: I have just found out how to do this with JS, using this code $("#dropdailyskin").click(function(){
  $("#dailyskins").show(200);
});

$("#dropdailyskin").click(function(){
  $("#topmods").hide(200);
});

$("#dropdownmods").click(function(){
  $("#dailyskins").hide(200);
});

$("#dropdownmods").click(function(){
  $("#topmods").show(200);
});, How would a add a different effect to this ? like fadeIn

Comment: Note that this does not actually delay the execution of your function but only slows down the animation.
To change the effect you can for example use `slideDown()` or `fadeIn()`

Comment: Thats perfect thank you !, is there any other effects ? i don't know what to search for to find more ?

Comment: Here you go, this page lists all available effects: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_effects.asp

Comment: thanks a lot! its finally looking like i wanted it to :D sorry I've been hard work (I'm 16) your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I was able to help - keep the good work up :-)

Answer (score 14):

Just add the .delay to your code like this

```
$("idhere").delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
```

its in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

or you can use.

```
$("idhere").delay(1000).show();
```